# Trouble installing USBDM for Freescale microcontroller after Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, usb

When I try to install usbdm (Version 4.12 released October 2018) by downloading the .deb from https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbdm/ and manually installing it with:

`dpkg -i usbdm_4.12.1.210-1-x86_64.deb`

I get the error that **libxerces-c3.1** is missing.

Answer (score 1):

USBDM v4.12 requires libxerces-c3.1, however libxerces-c3.1 was replaced with libxerces-c3.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

There is no problem with installing it as it does not conflict.  However, it has a couple of dependencies.

So:

1. From the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS package pages, download [libxerces-c3.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libxerces-c3.1/download) and [libicu55](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libicu55/download)
2. Install libicu55 with `dpkg -i libicu55*.deb`
3. Install libxerces-c3.1 with `dpkg -i libxerces-c3.1*.deb`
4. Install usbdm as before with `dpkg -i usbdm_4.12.1.210-1-x86_64.deb`